# c# button click events

Tags: c#, buttonclick

i have 3 forms in my program: FormA, FormB, and FormC.

in FormA, i have a search button, and when i click on this search button, FormC will pop up which only contain a textbox, and a button.

what i am trying to do is to call the search button in FormA from FormB to trigger FormC.

So, I click a button in FormB, i will performclick on the search button(FormA), and formC will popup.

I want to be able to input text into formC directly from FormA when i click on performclick, is that possible?

Thanks

```
        private void QuickChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BigTabCollections.SelectedIndex = 0;
        SearchOrderBtn.PerformClick();

    }
```

this is the function from FormB, it would go to formA and performClick, another Form will show up after that, and i would like to be able to input some text into the new popup form directly from this function.

Comment: Write code that actually does something as separate functions and call them instead of the event handlers. While not really different, this makes understanding what you do easier. Also: Don't only post your homework, post what you think could work and what you have tried.

Comment: this is not a homework, i am trying to add a new function into the program, but i got stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can access controls from another Form by setting the Form and it Controls to public, here a little sample:

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
     {
         public Form2()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         public string GetSetControlValue
         {
             get { return this.txtControl.Text; }
             set { this.txtControl.Text = value; }
         }
     }

    // In Form1 you can access the control like this:
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Form2 form2= new Form2();
         form2.GetSetControlValue = "Hello, world.";
         form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```